# Help with the proof that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ with finite perimeter and area has to be equal to the finite union of bounded intervals

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, analysis, geometric-measure-theory

*I'm preparing for an exams and I've problems solving this exercise from an old exam, any help will be welcomed*

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $\mathfrak{L}^1(E)<\infty$ and $$P(E) = \sup\biggl\{\int_E\varphi'(x)\,dx:\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\biggr\}<\infty.$$

> Prove that $E$ is (equivalent to, up to a set of measure $0$) the union of a finite number of bounded
>   intervals.

In here $P(E)$ is just a formal way to define the perimeter, so the problem is proving that, **if a subset of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ has finite length and finite perimeter then it is the union of a finite number on bounded intervals**.

My problem is how to put together the two datas we have on $E$ (the finite perimeter and finite length).

I actually found a proof of this fact but it seems quite convoluted so I was hoping to find some help in understanding it or even better state it in a simpler way

This come from the book *"Sets of finite perimeter and geometric variational problems"* from *Francesco Maggi*

[image]

**EDIT:** My idea is to pass to the closure and then argue with connected components of the former, also using the fact that for balls $P(E)=H^{n-1}(E)$ the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, this ball will need to be bounded and each of them giving a finite contribution to the perimeter therefore in a finite number.
However to do so I need $\overline{E}\setminus E$ to have measure 0 and even if I'm quite sure about this in the comments of this own post it doesn't seem like so.

Comment: Define "equivalent" please. I'm guessing it means "equal up to a set of measure zero", by it would be nice to say it explicitly, since it's not standard.

Comment: @Sam I corrected, I indeed mean up to a set of measure 0

Comment: @cmk I actually just thought about it for a long time but no actual attempt to solve it came to my mind, I don't seem to find a way to tackle the problem

Comment: I guess the real problem is how to reduce to the case where $E$ has nice topological properties. E.g. if we knew, that we can take $E$ to be closed, then it is rather easy to see that it must be true (for every connected component we can only pick up a contribution of $2$ be the fundamental theorem of calculus). However, I know no GMT, so I am not aware of any theorem allowing us to assume any nice topological property.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think that we can assume it to be closed.
Correct me if I'm wrong but every set in $\mathbb{R}$ if different from it's closure simply by some points, i.e. sets whose measure is 0.
Can you elaborate on the closed case?

Comment: @Frankie123 $E$ and $\overline{E}$ can differ by a set of positive measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to prove, by *reductio ad absurdum* (contradiction), that the sought for result is basically a consequence of the Archimedean property of real numbers: despite being relatively short, it is a "pseudo-elementary" proof since it involves the use of [Vitali's Covering Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma) in the form given by Gordon ([2], chapter 4, pp. 52-54).

**New edit**: after the comment by @Del I realized that the first step in equation \eqref{2}, should be fully justified: that step is implied by the following relation
$$
E\cap\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\underset{{\mu_\mathfrak{L}}}{\simeq}\,\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\iff \mu_\mathfrak{L}\left(E\cap\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\right) = \mu_\mathfrak{L}\left(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\right) \label{3}\tag{N}
$$
and a full justification of \eqref{3}, using the definition of Lebesgue's outer measure and [Caratheodory's criterion for measurability of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion) is given in the appendix section.

**Notation**.

- In the development below we consider only *finite i.e. bounded or proper intervals*.
- In order to simplify the (and by abuse of) notation, we use the symbol $\Bbb N$ for the set of *positive integers*, excluding $0$.
- $\mu_\mathfrak{L}$ stands for the *Lebesgue measure* and $\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast$ for the corresponding *outer measure*: obviously, $E$ is (Lebesgue) measurable if and only if $\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast=\mu_\mathfrak{L}$.

**The perimeter of an interval.**
Let $I=[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $-\infty<a\leq b<+\infty$ be a finite interval: then
$$
\begin{split}
P(I) & = \sup\Biggl\{\int\limits_I\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x:\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\Biggr\}\\
&=\sup\biggl\{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a):\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\biggr\}=
\begin{cases} 
0 &\text{if }a=b\\
2 &\text{if }a\neq b
\end{cases}.
\end{split}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Thus *the perimeter of an interval is always $2$ unless its Lebesgue measure is zero*.

**The structure of sets of finite perimeter on the real line.**
Let's introduce the deeper tool used in this answer: a strong form of Vitali's Covering lemma which holds true for *any subset* of the real line and involves only the analysis of its outer measure.

**Definition** (Gordon [2], p. 5). Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. A collection (family) $\mathscr{I}$ of intervals is a *Vitali covering* of $E$ if for each $x\in E$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists an interval $I\in\mathscr{I}$ such that $x\in I$ and $\mu_\mathfrak{L}(I)<\epsilon$.

**Vitali's Covering Lemma** (Gordon ([2], chapter 4, lemma 4.5, pp. 52-54). Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast(E)<\infty$. If $\mathscr{I}$ is a Vitali covering of $E$, then for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a finite collection $\{I_k\}_{k\in (n)}=\{I_k: 1\le k\le n\}$ of disjoint intervals in $\mathscr{I}$ such that
$$
\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast\left(E\setminus\bigcup^n_{k=1} I_k\right)<\epsilon.
$$
In addition, there exists a sequence  $\{I_k\}_{k\in \Bbb N}$ of disjoint intervals in $\mathscr{I}$ such that
$$
\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast\left(E\setminus\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\right)=0.
$$
Now, considering the additivity of the integral as a set function, \eqref{1} and a sequence $\{I_k\}_{k\in \Bbb N}$ which satisfies the Covering lemma, we have:
$$
\begin{split}
P(E) &= \sup\Biggl\{\,\int\limits_E\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x:\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\Biggr\}\\
& = \sup\Biggl\{\:\int\limits_{\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k}\!\!\!\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \;\;\,+\!\!\!\! \int\limits_{E\setminus\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x:\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\Biggr\}\\
& = \sup\Biggl\{\:\int\limits_{\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k}\!\!\!\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x :\varphi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\wedge |\varphi|_{\infty}\le 1\Biggr\}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(I_k)= 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta({I_k})
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where the set function $\delta(A)$ is defined as follows
$$
\delta_{A}=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }A=\emptyset\\
1 &\text{if }A\neq\emptyset
\end{cases}
$$
Now, from \eqref{2} we immediately see that $I_k$ must be empty for $k$ larger than some $k>n\in\Bbb N$ for if otherwise the perimeter of $E$ cannot be finite: thus ***$E$ is (equivalent to, up to a set of measure $0$) to the union of a finite number of bounded intervals***.

**Appendix: proof of the relation \eqref{3}**.

Let's recall the definition of outer measure of a set:
$$
\mu^\ast(E)=\inf_{\mathscr{C}=\mathcal{C}(E)}\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{I_k\in \mathscr{C}}I_k\right)
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all covering of $E$ made of intervals. Thus, by elementary considerations from real analysis, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist a covering $\mathscr{I}$ of $E$ such that
$$
\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{I_k\in \mathscr{I}}I_k\right) < \mu^\ast(E)+\varepsilon\label{4}\tag{A1}
$$
Now, $\mathscr{I}$ can be extended to a Vitali covering by simply adding to it the family of intervals $\{[-2^{-n}+x_o,2^{-n}+x_o]\cap I_k\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for all $x_o\in E$, where $I_k$ can be any interval containing $x_o$ chosen from the covering $\mathscr{I}$. Therefore we can apply Vitali's covering lemma to the family $\mathscr{I}$ in \eqref{4} and obtain a sequence of disjoint intervals intervals $\{I_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}\subseteq\mathscr{I}$ such that
$$
\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)\le \mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{I_k\in \mathscr{I}}I_k\right) \le \mu^\ast(E)+\varepsilon\iff \mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)\le  \mu^\ast(E) \label{5}\tag{A2}
$$
Now, since
$$
E\setminus\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k = E\cup\left(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\!\right)^{\!\!c},
$$
we can apply \eqref{5} and Caratheodory's condition (since $E$ is measurable) and get
$$
\begin{split}
\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)&\le 
\mu^\ast(E) \\
& = \mu^\ast\left(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)+\mu^\ast\left(E\cup\left(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\!\right)^{\!\!c}\right)\\
& = \mu^\ast\left(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)+\mu^\ast\left(E\setminus\bigcup^\infty_{k=1} I_k\right)\\
&= \mu^\ast\left(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right).
\end{split}
$$
But since $E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$, then
$$
\mu^\ast\left(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right) \le \mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right) \iff \mu^\ast\left(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right) =\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)\blacksquare
$$
**Final notes**

- I do not need to use geometric measure theory prove the result: however, the proof is not entirely elementary since versions of Vitali's Covering Lemma for unbounded sets seem not so easy to found in the literature. Indeed, apart from Gordon ([2], chapter 4, pp. 52-54), Kannan and Krueger ([3] §0.3, Th. 0.3.21, pp. 15-17) offer a proof (which also deals explicitly $n$-dimensional sets) but requires a more elaborate definition of Vitali covering ([2] §0.3, Def. 0.3.20, p. 15): the latter authors acknowledge Saks ([1], §IV.3, Th. 3.1, pp. 109-111) for the proof.
  Finally, Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara ([1] §2.4, Th. 2.18, pp. 52-53) give a proof similar to the ones of Kannan and Kruger/Saks but for [general (Radon) measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure).
- Note that *the perimeter of a subset of the real line*, when finite, *is always an even integer*, and this (at least in my opinion) discloses perhaps intriguing relations between the act of counting (in dimension one) and the finiteness of the perimeter (in dimension $n>1$).
- **Note on the appendix**. The intuition behind the proof of the relation \eqref{3} is the following one: let $E$ be one of the following sets
  $$
  E=
  \begin{cases}
  ]-1, 0[\cap \big\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb N\big\}\\
  \qquad\text{ or}\\
  ]-1,0[\cap \mathcal{C}
  \end{cases} 
  $$
  where $\mathcal{C}$ is the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). Then, while it is not possible to cover $E$ by a family of disjoint of intervals which has the same Lebesgue outer measure, nevertheless by applying Vitali's covering theorem you can find a family of such kind that has exactly the same measure since it avoids covering subsets of zero measure.

**References**

[1] Ambrosio, Luigi and Fusco, Nicola and Pallara, Diego (2000), *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*. Oxford Mathematical Monographs. New York and Oxford: The Clarendon Press/Oxford University Press, New York, pp. xviii+434, ISBN 0-19-850245-1, [MR1857292](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1857292), [Zbl 0957.49001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0957.49001).

[2] Gordon, Russell A., *The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock*, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 4. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xi, 395 p. (1994), ISBN: 0-8218-3805-9, [MR1288751](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1288751), [Zbl 0807.26004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0807.26004).

[3] Kannan, Rangachary and Krueger, Carole King, *Advanced analysis on the real line*, Universitext. New York, NY: Springer. ix, 259 p. (1996), ISBN: 0-387-94642-X, [MR1390758](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1390758), [Zbl 0855.26001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0855.26001).

[4] Saks, Stanisław, *Theory of the integral*, 2nd, revised ed. Engl. translat. by L. C. Young. With two additional notes by Stefan Banach. (English), Monografie Matematyczne Tom. 7. New York: G. E. Stechert & Co. pp. vi+347 (1937), [JFM 63.0183.05](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A63.0183.05), [MR0167578](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0167578) (review of the Dover ed.), [Zbl 0017.30004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0017.30004).

Comment: Shouldn't the decomposition be $E=\left(E\cap\bigcup_k I_k\right)\cup\left(E\setminus \bigcup_k I_k\right)$? In this case the third line in $(2)$ would have an integral over $E\cap \bigcup_k I_k$, and not over $E$ (they could differ on a positive set, because the Lemma says something only about the difference, not the symmetric difference).

Comment: @Del nice observation. I have to check if the measurability of $E$ could be used in order to solve this issue, since in this case $\mu_\mathfrak{L}^\ast=\mu_\mathfrak{L}$ and we can try to see if [Caratheodory's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion) is of some use.

Comment: Probably the outer regularity of Lebesgue measure is sufficient to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

In case you fancy Lebesgue density point there is a fairly simple argument that goes as follows: Suppose $a<b$ are Lebesgue density points of $E$ and $E^c$, respectively. Then by Lebesgue density we may to any $\epsilon>0$ find $\delta>0$ so that $\lambda([a,a+\delta]\cap E)\geq (1-\epsilon)\delta$ and $\lambda([b-\delta,b]\cap E)\leq \epsilon \delta$.

Now construct a bump-function $\phi\in C_c^1[a,b]$ so that $\phi(x)=1$ on $[a+\delta,b-\delta]$ which is almost linearly ("almost" in order to make the function $C^1$, costing some extra $\epsilon$ below)  increasing, respectively decreasing on the small intervals to the left and to the right.
Then
$$ \int_a^b \phi' 1_E =\int_a^{a+\delta} \phi' 1_E + \int_{b-\delta}^b \phi' 1_E \geq (1-2\epsilon) \int_a^{a+\delta} \phi' - 2\epsilon \int_{b-\delta}^b \phi'\geq 1-4\epsilon.$$

Now, if $a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<...<a_n<b_n$ is an intertwined sequence of density points in $E$ and $E^c$, respectively, you get by simply adding the corresponding bump-functions:
  $$P(E)=\sup\bigg \{ \int_E \phi' : \phi\in C_c^1({\Bbb R}), |\phi|_\infty\leq 1\bigg\} \geq n .$$
Thus, $n$ must be finite. In general, if $I$ is any nontrivial interval and $$0<\lambda(I\cap E)<\lambda(I)$$ then $I$ contains density points of both of the above types. So there can only be finitely many disjoint intervals that verifies this inequality. From this, the result follows easily.

Remark: Using a more clever construction of functions $\phi$ being zero at $\pm \infty$ and varying between $-1$ and $+1$ at a sequence of intertwined density points you realize that $P(E)$ simply counts the number of essential boundary points of $E$.